# F# csv type provider auto capitalize first letter of column names?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Just now I upgraded my F# CSV provder, the column names are all broken. It seems to me it is due to a switch in the CSV provider that auto converts the column names to first letter capitalized version. I googled and couldn't find any note about such breaking change.

Can someone point to me the relevant change-log / release note please?

Comment: Which CSV provider are you using? Which version did you update from, and which did you update to?  Most of the common TPs are open source, so it should be possible to track down such a change.